# How to set up an AWS key associated with IAM to restrict permissions available to an aws-sdk client?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We would like to limit the exposure/risk of an ec2 instance in case it gets hacked.  The only functions the instance needs to perform requiring AWS privileges is to upload to S3. Specifically we are using the `aws-sdk` library in `javascript` as follows:

```
    let s3 = new AWS.S3({
      accessKeyId: ID,
      secretAccessKey: SECRET,
      region: REGION
    });
```

Then we upload :

```
    s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            throw `S3 uploading failed on ${fname} : ${err}`;
        }
        console.log(`Uploaded ${msgIn.length} bytes to ${fname} successfully at S3 ${data.Location}`);
    });
```

But that `aws` key has full permissions to do just about anything in AWS. We can't have that .. So I looked into `IAM` - which has the right kinds of restrictions:

[image]

I was hoping to create `AWS` access keys from that `IAM role`. Can that be done? Or is there a different way to use the `aws-sdk` to get the restricted permissions for just s3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Using an IAM Role to Grant Permissions to Applications Running on Amazon EC2 Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html).

Essentially:

- create an IAM role with the relevant permissions
- launch EC2 (or modify existing EC2) with that role
- do not provide any credentials to the AWS SDK (it will retrieve credentials automatically)

Comment: Thx that's helpful - especially that last one: I could not find how to pass in temp creds: since actually one does not!

Comment: And those credentials are time-limited and will automatically rotate, which is a better security practice than persistent credentials. The SDK will take care of refreshing its copy of the creds as needed.